# Spark: groupBy with conditions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a `groupBy` for a `DataFrame` which is based on 3 columns. I am doing something like this:

```
myDf.groupBy($"col1", $"col2", $"col3")
```

Anyway I am not sure how this works.

Does it manage ignore cases? I need that for each column `"FOO"` and `"foo"` are considered the same like "" and null.

If this is not the supposed working mode how I can add it? From the API doc I can see something with `apply` on a column but I could not find any example.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you be more precise? It is not exactly clear what you want and how it is related to grouping.

Comment: not sure at this point. I stopped to use Dataframe and I am using only RDD. I get the same things done instead of 20 hours in only 50 mins. So at this point I am not sure if keep on using groupBy.

Answer (score 2):

You can run functions inside of your groupBy statement.  So in this case it sounds like you will want to convert the strings to lower case when you are grouping them.  Check out the lower function

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$